# Are there Integer performance counters on current Intel CPUs?

Tags: cpu, hpc

I would like to measure the Integer calculation performance of a code that performs sparse matrix-matrix calculations. Are there performance counters on Intel CPU similar to those for float/double calculations?

More specifically I would like to count Integer additions, multiplications, fused add/mul and comparisions. But any subset will be helpful.

I couldn't find any such events when using [likwid-perfctr](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid) to read performance counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the CPU. You can check the complete list of available performance events in different microarchitectures [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-amplifier-help-intel-processor-events-reference). There could be events for both integer and floating-point operations or for just integer operations. For example, on Nehalem, `ARITH.DIV` and `ARITH.MUL` count the number of integer and floating-point divisions and multiplications executed, respectively. There are also the `SIMD_INT_*` performance events for counting only integer SIMD operations. On Skylake, the only event that might approximate what you need is `ARITH.DIVIDER_ACTIVE`, which counts the number of cycles when the divide unit is busy executing both integer and floating-point divisions.

Generally, you can search for events that have `INT` in their name or `integer` in their description. You can find most of the events this way, but not all of them.

You should be very careful when using these events. You should understand how they work when SMT is enabled, exactly what is being counted and what is not, and how fused add/multiply operations are treated. Unfortunately, the documentation tends to be vague in that regard, so you may need to experiment with them first.